# Nested dict in python, searching based on inner key get inner value and parent key

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

I have following dict:

```
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, 
{'11': {('extreme_fajita', 'jalapeno_poppers'): '4',('test12', 'test14'): '5'}, 
 '10': {('jalapeno_poppers', 'test', ): '2', ('test2',): '3', ('test14',): '5'}
}
```

And I want to search on based on inner key i.e `('test2',)` I should get the value from inner dictionary and parent key (outer key)

i.e searching for `('test2',)` I should get get `['10', '3']`  or whole like  `['10', '('test2', )', '3']`

Comment: what output do you want exactly?

Comment: inner `test2` has value `('test2',): '3'` how it get value as `['2', '3']` or `['2', (`test2`, ), '3']` ? from where it get value `2` ?

Comment: sorry it should be '10' , i have updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume your `defaultdict` looks like:

```
defaultdict = {'11': {('extreme_fajita', 'jalapeno_poppers'): '4',('test12', 'test14'): '5'}, '10': {('jalapeno_poppers', 'test2', ): '2', ('test2',): '3', ('test14',): '5'} }
```

If that's the case, then you can use:

```
searchValue = 'test2'; found = []
for masterkey,mastervalue in defaultdict.iteritems():
    for childkey,childvalue in mastervalue.iteritems():
        if searchValue in childkey:
            found.append(childvalue)
print found
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is not ordered so you will not get in the order as '2','3' instead you can get all values from the dictionary where 'test2' found. I have following code for this:

```
def getKeys(d1, path="", lastDict=list()):
    for k in d1.keys():
        if type(k) is tuple:
            if 'test2' in k:
                print "test2 found at::", path + "->" , k
                print "Value of test2::", d1[k]
                print "Values in parent::", [kl for kl in lastDict[len(lastDict)-1].values()]
        elif type(d1[k]) is dict:
            lastDict.append(d1[k])
            if path == "":
                path = k
            else:
                path = path + "->" + k
            getKeys(d1[k], path)

d = {'11': {('extreme_fajita', 'jalapeno_poppers'): '4',('test12', 'test14'): '5'}, '10': {('jalapeno_poppers', 'test', ): '2', ('test2',): '3', ('test14',): '5'}}
getKeys(d)
```

Output:

```
test2 found at:: 11->10-> ('test2',)
Value of test2:: 3
Values in parent:: ['2', '5', '3']
```